# Extract field from /proc/meminfo file

Tags: linux, memory, awk, grep, cat

/proc/meminfo file gives the cpu requirements of a machine. The out out of the command is as follows:

```
MemTotal:        2002424 kB
MemFree:         1061248 kB
MemAvailable:    1562492 kB
Buffers:           79584 kB
Cached:           522376 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           450252 kB
Inactive:         332780 kB
Active(anon):     181772 kB
Inactive(anon):       92 kB
Active(file):     268480 kB
Inactive(file):   332688 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                64 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        181028 kB
Mapped:           147104 kB
Shmem:               796 kB
Slab:             111516 kB
SReclaimable:      62984 kB
SUnreclaim:        48532 kB
KernelStack:        3680 kB
PageTables:         8908 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     1001212 kB
Committed_AS:    1177904 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      133096 kB
DirectMap2M:     1925120 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

How to extract `2002424` of `Total Memory` using $cat command in Linux, or using `awk`, `grep`?

Comment: Welcome to SO, your sample input is not clear. Please be clear in your samples of input and expected output, kindly do EDIT your question and let us know then.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) to catch the desired line and [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to get the desired column (5);

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep 'Total Memory' | awk '{print $5}'
```

Even better; just use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)! Start from behind and remove the first column ('kB') with: `$(NF-1)`! Thx [@karakfa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1435869/karakfa)!

```
awk '/Total Memory/{print $(NF-1)}' /proc/meminfo
```

Result;

> 2002424

Comment: `awk '/Total Memory/{print $(NF-1)}'  /proc/meminfo`

Comment: Better `awk '/MemTotal/{print $(NF-1)}'  /proc/meminfo` - the `"Total Memory of"` was a typo in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression `/: */` as field separator with GNU awk 4.2.1 you'll get for example:

```
> awk -F': *' -v var='MemTotal' '$1 == var { print $2 }' /proc/meminfo 
4029952 kB
```

If you want to deal with number and unit separately, then split field `$2` at white space into array `f` using `split($2, f, / +/)`, and you'll get:

```
> awk -F': *' -v var='MemTotal' '$1 == var { split($2, f, / +/); print $1 "=" f[1] f[2] }' /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal=4029952kB
```

With GNU awk 4.2.1 and Linux 4.12.14 I did not need an extra `cat /proc/meminfo` to feed `awk`.

So to match the question best, my answer would be one of the variants following:

```
> awk -F': *' -v var='MemTotal' '$1 == var { split($2, f, / +/); print f[1] }' /proc/meminfo 
4029952
```

```
> awk -F': *' '$1 == "MemTotal" { split($2, f, / +/); print f[1] }' /proc/meminfo 
4029952
```

I think this obsoletes the answer from @0stone0.